# Vba Cell Selection Based on Value

Tags: excel, vba

I couldn't find anything asking quite what I am looking for...

I am using two conditions to set my selection (Finding the value "Reducer", then in the cell directly below it, finding "" {an empty cell}).

I am having trouble finding a way to select the cells that match these criteria and then listing the cell address (I want to display the cell address in a message box, alerting them of the location of the 'error')

Eventually there will be many more cells to look for, which is why I want to search through multiple cells.

So in a nutshell, I want my code to find the two criteria, select the cell matching the criteria, and show a pop-up message stating which cell the error is in.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If ActiveSheet.Range("J11").Value < 0 Then
    MsgBox "You have exceeded the maximum allowable pipe length for this section. Please review your selection before continuing. ", vbOKOnly, "Inoperable Pipe Length"
End If

Do While ActiveSheet.Range("J17,J7").Value = "Reducer"
   If ActiveSheet.Range("J18,J8").Value = "" Then
        G = Sheets("Pipe Calcs").Range("J18,J8").Address
        MsgBox "Please Select a reducer size in cell " & G & ActiveCell.Address(False, False), vbCritical, "No Reducer Size Selected"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        End
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value < 0 Then
    MsgBox "You have exceeded the maximum allowable pipe length for this section. Please review your selection before continuing. ", vbOKOnly, "Inoperable Pipe Length"
End If

For Each cell In Range("J1:J1000")
    If cell.Value = "Reducer" Then
        If Range(cell.Address).Offset(1, 0) = "" Then
        G = Sheets("Pipe Calcs").Range(cell.Address).Offset(1, 0).Address
        MsgBox "Please Select a reducer size in cell " & G
        Range(Cell.Address).Offset(1, 0).Select
        Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
Next


End Sub
```

The above code will check column `J` for "Reducer", if found, it will see if the cell below contains a value, if it doesn't it will prompt the user for the cell and exit the sub. When the user updates the cell, they trigger the `Worksheet_Change` statement and cause the macro to run again.

Comment: This did the trick, thank you so much. I guess I was trying to be way too pinpoint with what cells I checked to begin with. For some reason I could never get the cell address to ever come up in my code. 

Regardless, thank you very much!

Comment: @Keegan the reason you could never get the `.address` to work with your ranges is because your range was fixed across multiple cells. `.address` needs a single cell to look at to return the address. With the code above, because you loop through 1 cell at a time, the `cell.address` is always referencing one cell only as opposed to `range(J18,J8)` which is looking at 2 cells at the same time

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. That makes a lot more sense now.